# UDP WinSock - Not Receiving Broadcast Packets

Tags: c++, c, udp, winsock, broadcasting

I'm testing a simple socket setup in which a server listens on a specified port, and a client sends a broadcast packet which should be received by that server.

This setup works fine when sending messages directly (i.e. not broadcasting), but when broadcasting the packet is never received on the server.

Some of the code (trimmed down with error checking removed, for simplicity):

```
// Client (broadcast sender)

// Create and bind the client socket
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

sockaddr_in sockAddr;
sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
sockAddr.sin_port = htons(5678);
sockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

bind(clientSocket, (sockaddr*)(&sockAddr), sizeof(sockAddr));

u_long uMode = 1;
ioctlsocket(clientSocket, FIONBIO, &uMode);

char broadcast = 1;
setsockopt(clientSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcast, sizeof(broadcast));

// ...

// Send the packet
sockaddr_in sockAddress;
sockAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
sockAddress.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = htonl(INADDR_BROADCAST);
sockAddress.sin_port = htons(5679);

char const* pPacket = "Test";
size_t uPacketSize = strlen(pPacket) + 1;

sendto(clientSocket, pPacket, (int)uPacketSize, 0, (sockaddr*)&sockAddress, sizeof(sockAddress));
```

-

```
// Server (listener)

// Create and bind the server socket
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

sockaddr_in sockAddr;
sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
sockAddr.sin_port = htons(5679);
sockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

bind(serverSocket, (sockaddr*)(&sockAddr), sizeof(sockAddr));

u_long uMode = 1;
ioctlsocket(serverSocket, FIONBIO, &uMode);

// ...

char pBuffer[1024];
while (true)
{
    int iRecvSize = recv(serverSocket, pBuffer, 1024, 0);
    if (iRecvSize)
    {
        printf("Received packet\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to add error checking for more functions, like for example the `setsockopt` calls.

Comment: You *also* need to set the `SO_BROADCAST` option on the socket you want to *receive* the broadcast on.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I do have error checking in the actual code, I just removed it for this question. None of the functions are returning any errors (except the occasional WSAEWOULDBLOCK, which is to be expected for non-blocking sockets).
I think I did try setting SO_BROADCAST on the receiver, but I'll try that again and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

(Should be a comment, but my reputation is not high enough)

I don't know if this applies to you, but there is a unintuitive behavior with broadcasts on recent versions of Windows. If you have multiple physical Ethernet adapters, broadcasts will only be received on the "preferred" interface (where "preference" is determined by Windows' routing table)

See the following for an explanation and potential fix:
https://github.com/dechamps/WinIPBroadcast

Another temporary fix would be to disable all other network adapters to make sure the broadcast is received on the correct one (in Control Panel/Network and Sharing Center/Change adapter settings).

Comment: I tried disabling all but one network adapter, but the result was the same - the packet never gets received. Would this problem also affect testing locally (i.e. with the client and server running in separate threads of the same process)?

Comment: @yothsoggoth I don't think I had the problem locally but I was testing with 2 different processes. I'm not sure what the behavior would be for 2 threads of the same application. I can only suggest Wireshark if you're not already using it to debug.