# WinSock - UDP Broadcast Listener

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, sockets, winsock

I have a device which sends out data packets via the UDP broadcast address.

I'm attempting to put together a winsock application to listen for these broadcast messages but ultimately, I'm not having much success setting up a UDP socket.

Here's he code I have to create the socket and start the listener thread:

```
DWORD CreateStatusListener() {
    WORD wVersion;
    WSADATA wsa;
    int err;

    wVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    err = WSAStartup(wVersion, &wsa);

    if (err != 0) {
        // Fail gracefully
        // ...
    }

    // Create the UDP status socket
    m_iSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    if (m_iSocket == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        // Fail gracefully
        // ...
    }

    m_bAbort = FALSE;

    // Create the UDP status socket listener thread
    m_hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, PollStatusSocket, NULL, 0, &m_dwThreadID);

    if (!m_hThread) {
        // Fail gracefully
        // ...
    }

    return ERR_SUCCESS;
}
```

This function succeeds, with the socket being set up and the thread being created.

My UDP polling function is as follows:

```
static DWORD WINAPI PollStatusSocket(LPVOID lpParam) {

    struct sockaddr_in socket;
    INT length;

    // Set up the address struct
    memset(&socket, 0, sizeof(socket));
    socket.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socket.sin_port = htons(52102);
    socket.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_BROADCAST;

    INT err = SOCKET_ERROR;
    INT bAllow = 1;

    err = setsockopt(m_iSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (char *)&bAllow, sizeof(bAllow));

    // Allocate a receive buffer
    char ucBuffer[BUFFER_LEN];

    // Loop while the thread is not aborting
    while (!m_bAbort) {
        err = recvfrom(m_iSocket, ucBuffer, BUFFER_LEN, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&socket, &length);

        if (err != SOCKET_ERROR) {
            // Check we have a valid status message
            // ...
        }
        else {
            err = WSAGetLastError();

            printf("Error: %d", err);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What happens during the polling thread is that `recvfrom` returns -1 and the `WSAGetLastError` reports a `WSAEINVAL` error - invalid argument.

Some code examples I've seen use the `bind` method but as far as I was aware, I don't need to call `bind` on a broadcast address. One thing I have considered is whether the `sockaddr_in` struct was assigned correctly - for example, does the port number need to be passed as `htons(port)` or just as is?

Comment: Surely you should always use `htons()` for portability issues, the function will do the required conversions depending on the machine running the code. But if you're using it on an X86 architecture you **must use `htons()`** because network byte order is almost always big_endian.

Comment: @Frankie_C, in which case, should I use `htonl` when specifying the sin_addr? Either way, I'm still not able to receive UDP broadcast packets.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022253/udp-winsock-not-receiving-broadcast-packets, http://www.binarytides.com/udp-socket-programming-in-winsock/

Comment: You should bind the socket anyway, the broadcast address, defined as `#define INADDR_BROADCAST (u_long)0xffffffff` is anyway an address **`255.255.255.255`**.

Comment: Ok, so I've added a `bind` just after the `setsockopt`:

    `err = bind(m_iSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&socket, sizeof(socket));`

I get an error code of `10049` which is `WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL` cannot assign requested address

Comment: Well, I'm not sure that's the case in my instance. I've got Wireshark hooked up to my ethernet interface and I can see the UDP broadcast packets coming in on this interface

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the issue was with this line of code, specifically the last two parameters:

```
err = recvfrom(m_iSocket, ucBuffer, BUFFER_LEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&socket, &length);
```

`length` was never being initialized (should be `sizeof(sockaddr_in)`) and `&socket` should be a different `sockaddr_in` struct - not the one used during the `bind` call.

Sorry guys, overlooked that!